# How to make a updater for electron application

Tags: amazon-s3, ionic3, electron

I created a desktop application for my ionic app using electron. Now what I need is  I want to implement auto update function for this. I followed several documentations, but neither helps. 
https://discuss.atom.io/t/deploy-app-on-users-machine-with-autoupdate/40385/2 
Finally I followed steps in this document since it seems to be working after reading the comments. But it also didn't work.
Can someone guide me to resolve this?

Comment: What did you tried so far? And what do you expect from us?

Comment: @Batajus  I have mentioned the tutorial which I followed. But it didn’t give the results I expected.  Can you please help me to implement auto update function either from this method or another method

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: If you use electron-builder, you should read this https://www.electron.build/auto-update.html